# Tietze transformations and the translation of words

Tags: group-theory, transformation, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am new to combinatorial group theory and have a question regarding Tietze transformations. Say I have a group G, finitely presented by $\langle X | R \rangle$, and a sequence of (finitely many) Tietze transformations ending in $\langle X' | R' \rangle$, which in turn finitely presents a group $G'$. Further, say I want to translate a word $w$ (written in $X$ and its inverses) from $\langle X | R \rangle$ to an equivalent word $w'$ in $\langle X' |R' \rangle$ (i. e. a word $w'$ denoting the same group element in $G'$ as $w$ denoted in $G$, where $G \cong G'$).

Since Tietze transformations in general produce isomorphisms, would I just need to know the mapping of the generators of $X$ to the generators of $X'$ in order to aquire an equivalent word (i. e. one of many representations of the equivalent group element in $G'$ written in $X'$ and its inverses)? How would I need to account for a discrepancy in the numbers of generators in both presentations, in order to translate $w$ correctly?

Or to break down my question into single Tietze steps:

- When adding a new generator $y$, say to $X = \{ x_1, x_2, ... , x_n \}$ what do I map to the new generator $y$? As I understand, $y$ can be written in the generators $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ (or their inverses). Would it be necessary to map the preimage of y to y in order to translate the word $w$? I would assume it only being necessary, if the letter $y$ itself is to be part of the translation, since $y$ itself can be written in $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ (or their inverses)?
- When cancelling a generator, say $y$ (assuming there exists the relevant relator, say $ys^-1$, in $R$ to do so), I would need to map $y$ to $s$ ($s$ being written in $x_1, x_2, ...$ or their inverses). So I would need a map from all $x_i$ to $x_i$ as well as from $y$ to $s$.
- When adjusting only $R$ with a Tietze transformation the normal closure stays the same. So I would assume there is no mapping necessary for a translation of $w$  .

My question being, is my understanding correct, or am I missing something (or several things)?

Comment: You have a word in the original generators $X$. Adding a new generator doesn't change that word at all. The only thing you have to account for is removing a generator from $X$, which is done via a relation of the form $x_i=u$ for some word $u$ in generators other than $x_i$. At that time, replace all occurrences of $x_i$ in your word $w$ with $u$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @SteveD. I think I got a grasp of the "translations" by single Tietze steps and sequences of them.I also found it quite instructive to go through some examples (a basic one being the Tietze transformations on a presentation of $S_3$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations) ) and seeing that the translations of random words matched with the expected group elements (i. e. in the mentioned case: getting words in a new presentation of $S_3$ representing the same elements in cycle notation as the original words did).